# Filter does not seem to work (pwa-studio demo)

Tags: filter, pwa-studio

I cloned pwa studio 3.0.0 and [followed the instructions](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/):

```
git clone https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio.git
cd pwa-studio
yarn install
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/" yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept
yarn run build
yarn run watch:all
```

The shop is running and I can change category, if I select category  `bottoms` and then click the filter button I get filter options. Then I select price and check `$0.00 - $99.99`. When clicking `apply filter` the url changes but the list of articles stays the same.

No errors in console and no XHR in network tab. The `CATALOG/FILTER_OPTION/UPDATE` action is dispatched and changes are made to the state (before closing the filter slider).

I was wondering if I missed something and/or where to look to hook up the filter to the effect that gets me the data. Am I supposed to hook it up myself or is this a bug?

If I have to it myself then where would I do it, do I do it [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/pwa-studio/blob/d63b803/packages/venia-ui/lib/RootComponents/Category/category.js#L48-L65)?

*update*

Looks like the filter feature is not implemented. Adding a [price variable](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/pwa-studio/blob/d08891f/packages/venia-ui/lib/RootComponents/Category/category.js#L57) to runQuery and setting it as a [filter](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/pwa-studio/blob/d08891f/packages/venia-ui/lib/queries/getCategory.graphql#L21) will give me filtered results.

I am not sure what the intention is of the dev team but it looks like vinia-ui will get a [complete overhaul](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/tree/peregrine-implementation/convert-to-function-components/packages/venia-ui) so maybe not touching it until I'm clear what the dev team intends to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because [graphql part is not hooked up to configurable product.](https://github.com/magento/graphql-ce/issues/500)

> > what about filtering for things such as Fashion Material or size, etc? Those attributes are part of ConfigurableProduct but I wasn't able to filter for them. See magento/pwa-studio#1432